# How to run a python macro from a keyboard bind

Tags: python, macros, keyboard

I'm trying to add a hotkey to a script that'll be running in the background. I need it to activate after i press a hotkey in another window.

I tried to use a pyput library to do this however it collided with keyboard library so right now i'm looking into the keyboard.add.hotkey function, here is my code:

```
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard

keyboard.add.hotkey("shift+a"): exec(
    
    pyautogui.moveTo(1749, 753)
    pyautogui.click()
    time.sleep(0.4)

    #clicking on buy whehicle
    pyautogui.moveTo(955, 973)
    pyautogui.click()
    time.sleep(0.4)

    #clicking on free xp, 
    pyautogui.moveTo(1308, 584)
    pyautogui.click()
    time.sleep(0.01)
    keyboard.write('1000000')
    time.sleep(0.3)

    #clicking on spend resources
    pyautogui.moveTo(851, 988)
    pyautogui.click()
    time.sleep(0.3)

    #clicking confirm
    pyautogui.moveTo(859, 757)
    pyautogui.click()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mapping the shortcut to run the script with a middleman could probably accomplish this. Various free tools exist, such as https://www.autohotkey.com/, that could be used to call your script.
This could be implemented like this:

```html
# In Autohotkey
#below is "ctrl shift a", and should work from anywhere

^+a::
Run, path-to-program.py ;
```

Alternatively, you could have the script start from your IDE, and then navigate into your other window (I'm assuming a game?) like this:

```python
pyautogui.hotkey('alt','tab')
```

In lieu of having the script run from a hotkey, though this is likely less convienent.

Comment: Please note that there is probably a more correct way to do this, I didn't have rep to leave a normal comment so I had to format this as an answer.